# TicTacToe Minimax doesn't recognize that it will lose

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, pyautogui, minimax

I'm trying to develop a tic-tac-toe AI using the Minimax algorithm. I'm attempting to capture and update the board using a screenshot so that the AI can then react to it and apply the Minimax algorithm. It finds the best move to win, but doesn't recognize if it could lose in the next move.

In the Minimax function, there is access to return -1 (I verified this with print), but in the computer_move method, it is never taken into account if a move could return -1.

What can I adjust in my code to change that?

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

hell = (24, 188, 156)
dunkel = (44, 62, 80)

class Tic_Tac_Toe:
    global start

    def __init__(self):
        self.board = {1: " ", 2: " ", 3: " ", 4: " ", 5: " ", 6: " ", 7: " ", 8: " ", 9: " "}
        self.screen_board = {1: " ", 2: " ", 3: " ", 4: " ", 5: " ", 6: " ", 7: " ", 8: " ", 9: " "}
        self.dict_click_pos = {1: [692, 339], 2: [910, 338], 3: [1129, 341],
                               4: [686, 553], 5: [909, 558], 6: [1130, 564],
                               7: [690, 777], 8: [910, 777], 9: [1133, 781]}
        self.zahler = 0
        self.computer = "X"
        self.player = "O"

    def print_board(self, board):
        print(board[1] + "|" + board[2] + "|" + board[3])
        print("------")
        print(board[4] + "|" + board[5] + "|" + board[6])
        print("------")
        print(board[7] + "|" + board[8] + "|" + board[9])
        print("\n")

    def computer_move(self):
        self.player_move()
        bestScore = -800
        bestMove = 0
        for key in self.board.keys():
            if self.board[key] == " ":
                self.board[key] = self.computer
                score = self.minimax(self.board, False)
                self.board[key] = " "
                if score > bestScore:
                    bestScore = score
                    bestMove = key
        # press pixel where the best move is or should be
        pyautogui.click(self.dict_click_pos[bestMove][0], self.dict_click_pos[bestMove][1])

    def player_move(self):
        self.get_board()
        for key in self.screen_board.keys():
            if self.screen_board[key] != self.board[key]:
                self.board[key] = self.screen_board[key]

    def has_won(self):
        # i dont need this for this problem
        '''if self.check_win(self.player) == self.player:
            print(f"Glückwunsch! {self.player} hat gewonnen!")
        if self.check_win(self.computer) == self.computer:
            print(f"Glückwunsch! {self.computer} hat gewonnen!")'''
        return False

    def check_win(self, board, x_or_o):
        if (board[1] == board[2] and board[1] == board[3] and board[1] == x_or_o):
            return x_or_o
        elif (board[4] == board[5] and board[4] == board[6] and board[4] == x_or_o):
            return x_or_o
        elif (board[7] == board[8] and board[7] == board[9] and board[7] == x_or_o):
            return x_or_o
        elif (board[1] == board[4] and board[1] == board[7] and board[1] == x_or_o):
            return x_or_o
        elif (board[2] == board[5] and board[2] == board[8] and board[2] == x_or_o):
            return x_or_o
        elif (board[3] == board[6] and board[3] == board[9] and board[3] == x_or_o):
            return x_or_o
        elif (board[1] == board[5] and board[1] == board[9] and board[1] == x_or_o):
            return x_or_o
        elif (board[7] == board[5] and board[7] == board[3] and board[7] == x_or_o):
            return x_or_o
        else:
            return False

    def check_draw(self, board):
        for key in board.keys():
            if board[key] == " ":
                return False
        return True

    def minimax(self, board, isMaximizing):
        if self.check_win(board, self.player):
            return -1
        elif self.check_win(board, self.computer):
            return 1
        elif self.check_draw(board):
            return 0

        if isMaximizing:
            bestScore = -800
            for key in board.keys():
                if board[key] == " ":
                    board[key] = self.computer
                    score = self.minimax(board, False)
                    board[key] = " "
                    if score > bestScore:
                        bestScore = score
            return bestScore
        else:
            bestScore = 800
            for key in board.keys():
                if board[key] == " ":
                    board[key] = self.player
                    score = self.minimax(board, True)
                    board[key] = " "
                    if score < bestScore:
                        bestScore = score
            return bestScore

    def get_board(self):
        # Mache einen Screenshot des gesamten Bildschirms
        for key in self.dict_click_pos.keys():
            # Bestimme die Farbe des Pixels an der Koordinate (x, y)
            pixel_color = pyautogui.screenshot().getpixel((self.dict_click_pos[key][0], self.dict_click_pos[key][1]))
            if pixel_color == dunkel:
                self.screen_board[key] = "0"
            elif pixel_color == hell:
                self.screen_board[key] = "X"
            else:
                self.screen_board[key] = " "



t = Tic_Tac_Toe()

while not t.has_won():
        while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed("s"):
                t.computer_move()
                break
```

Normally it works fine but with the screenshot it takes the wrong move. The screenshot is from a tic tac toe board with the positions.

Comment: In `get_board` you use `0` (zero) for the player's symbol, but `self.player` is `O` (letter O).